# How to scale/zoom jquery dialogue in mobile devices

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, mobile, dialog

Is there any way to scale/ zoom the jquery dialogue box in mobile devices?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" />
```

This is my dialoge box jquery

```
(function($) {

$(document).ready(function() {
           redirect = wyConfirm('Error message', 'Alert');


});
/*jquery ui dialog for error message alerts*/


var wyAlertDialog = null;

window.wyConfirm = function(msg, title) {
    if (!title) {
        title = 'Message';
    }
    if ($('#wyalert_div').length == 0) {
        $('body').append('<div style="display:none;"><div id="wyalert_div"> </div></div>');
        wyConfirmDialog = $("#wyalert_div");
        wyConfirmDialog.dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            zIndex: 2000,
            OpacityOverlay: 1,
            height: 'auto',
            buttons: {
                "Confirm": function() {

                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    return true;
                },
                "Cancel": function() {

                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    $('#wyalert_div').html(msg);
    wyConfirmDialog.dialog('option', 'title', title);
    wyConfirmDialog.dialog('open');
    return false;
}

 })(jQuery);
```

but this is not working in all browsers especially android browser.

Comment: in an Android App's web view / browser ? Can you show your jQuery dialog box as well ?

Comment: Read [Using the viewport meta tag to control layout on mobile browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Comment: @ShivanRaptor, OP wants to achieve this on JQuery Mobile , not on Android i guess.

Comment: he mentioned *especially android browser*

Comment: this is not an android app, a mobile website